# Pivot Table Via VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to be able to use this macro to create this pivot table each day on the same worksheet name.  The only thing that will change is the datasource row as I never know how many rows it will be.  I tried to set the entire string into the CurSourceData variable and then just use that but it fails and says invalid arg.

Any ideas would be helpful.

```
Sheets("Cases 23+ Day (Due Today)").Select
 Range("A1").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
     Selection.End(xlDown).Select
CurRow = ActiveCell.Row
CurSourceData = "Cases 23+ Day (Due today)!R1C2:R" & CurRow & "C20"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    CurSourceData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Master Summary!R3C7", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Master Summary").Select
Cells(3, 7).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Status"), "Count of Status", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Status")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The SourceData argument of `PivotCaches.Create` is either a Range or a Connection. I think there's also a problem with the space in your sheet name and the answer is to use single quotes. Try :

`Set CurSourceData = Worksheets("Cases 23+ Day (Due today)").Range("B1", "T" & CurRow)`

(I detest R1C1 notation and couldn't work out how to use it here.)

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I did try changing that and that did not help. Any other ideas?  In addtion, if I actually use the correct correct information with "" as needed it errors out on slecting master summary too??

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, assuming your data set starts in cell A1:

```
Dim MyRange As Range

Dim lrow As Long

Dim lcol As Long

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lrow, lcol)
```

Good luck!